# Uniswap AmountOutIn fee calc

Tags: solidity, exchanges, fees

My question is did Uniswap and other dexes that have same concept of `amountOutMin` would calc it like that:
`amountOutMin = minimum amount that i want - the dex fee`
or
`amountOutMin = minimum amount that i want, and they will sub the fee and give me the rest`

In code:

```
// So i should calc the fee then ask for minimum
routerToBuy.swapExactTokensForTokens(amountIn, amountOutMin - fee, path, address(this), deadline);

// Or i ask for the minimum and they will sub the fee then give me the rest (amountOutMin - fee)
routerToBuy.swapExactTokensForTokens(amountIn, amountOutMin, path, address(this), deadline);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is 90% yes. Most of dexes at the moment are cloned from uniswap, eg: Pancakeswap, ApeSwap, Quickswap, etc. So, basically, if the dexes are forked from Uniswap, they have same calculation because they use the same infrastructure. On the other hand, if dexes are not forked from Uniswap, eg: KyberSwap, etc., they should have difference calculation.

Comment: Which one are correct `amountOutMin = minimum amount that i want - the dex fee` or  `amountOutMin = minimum amount that i want, and they will sub the fee and give me the rest`

Comment: The corrected one is amountOutMin = minimum amount that i want - the dex fee. Because amountOutMin is the minimum acceptable amount of output tokens that you want to receive after accounting for any fees (slippage tolerance). This ensures that even if the price slips due to market fluctuations or fees, you still receive at least the minimum amount you're willing to accept.

Comment: Another question: is `GetAmountsOut` will return the `output amount - fee` or `output amount`. so i need to calc fee with the result i get of `GetAmountsOut` or already calculated.